# Google login only works for me - SHA1 problem

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin

My app uses Google Login and only I can use Google login successfully because I used mine SHA1 which was generated from debug.keystore. When setting up Android Client in Google Cloud project I put mine SHA1. What is the best way to fix this problem so my colleagues can test Google login?

I tried to share debug.keystore with my colleagues but I don't think that is good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite a common practice to stick the debug keystore in the app repository when you have several collaborators on a project as it allows you to easily utilise services that rely on the SHA hashes for testing purposes (among other things).

The debug keystore is auto generated by Android Studio and uses `android` as the password, it's not really intended to be secure and it should only be used for debug/dev builds which would not be published anywhere.

You can configure it in `build.gradle.kts` (or `build.gradle`) with something like this:

```
signingConfigs {
    getByName("debug") {
        storeFile = file(project.rootDir.path + "/debug.keystore")
    }
}
```

This assumes you put the keystore in the project root.